# Is there a demo for TeeChart 2012 Standard or Professional  that compiles out of the box with a full installed non-trial version of TeeChart?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe2, teechart

TeeChart 2012 for Delphi, includes many demos, but the first one I thought I'd try is the features\tee9new.dpr demo, a monster of a demo which appears to be hard-coded to contain over 200 unit references to units that only ship in the high-end TeeChart product SKUs, and so the demo doesn't build out of the box, even though it ships in teeChart standard, it's a useless demo.

It appears there are zero "just your basic TChart demo" demos included with the package.

Maybe I'm missing something.  But at some point the **Features** demo became all about gradients and polar maps, and crap that isn't in TeeChart 2012 standard.

If there isn't one provided by Steema, can someone point me at a demo that does the following three things:

1. Create at least five types of charts (bar, line, series, etc).
2. Show the recommended code patterns for working with charts every day.

I am currently hacking the Features demo to remove stuff that doesn't build in standard, but surely there must be something like this out there already?  I have spent over an hour hacking on the demo and it seems I'm nowhere close to dealing with the "things that don't work in standard or pro".

I'm currently attempting to get ANY demo running in delphi 7, 2007, and xe2.

Comment: Have you asked Steema this question?  It's generally best to go to them first when the question is about their product.

Comment: They actually are apparently on here, and since all users (even trial users) can access this, Steema says its' better to ask HERE. Their forums and support are for registered users only and I thought this is a helpful, useful general question about a very popular Delphi component, so I'll ask it here. While I'm a licensed user, I think that anyone using Delphi, any version, might want to try out the full tee chart component trial, and then run a demo.

Comment: That's reasonable. If I'd noticed your high reputation (16.4k at the time of this writing) I probably would have inferred that there was a good reason for your asking this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the kind of demo you are asking for is not available but I have already prepared a simple example project using a few basic series styles, showing how to add data to them, letting the user display basic chart objects, etc. It's available [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/TeeChartStdDemo.zip). Following the guidelines at the tutorials provided you should be able to easily extend it.

Comment: Either a reduced version of the Features demo that has all the unavailable stuff removed, or else something small, and "tutorial like" in nature. Tutorial code with a demo would be very good indeed.  Hello World in TChart, up to some intermediate stuff, but skip the 3D zoom and pan stuff that the features demo starts with.

Comment: @WarrenP I have arranged a very simple project using a few basic series styles, showing how to add data to them, letting the user display basic chart objects, etc. The demo is available at http://www.steema.com/files/public/TeeChartStdDemo.zip. If you'd like to have any specific feature implemented on it don't hesitate to let me know.

Comment: @WarrenP you're welcome! BTW: A new beta update has been posted: http://www.steema.com/entry/116/TeeChart_.NET_Mono_for_Android_Library_BETA_update. We expect the next release being the final one.